# Создание "тунеля" c VPS

Tags: сеть, vps, vpn

Проблема: есть VPN (для работы), который у меня перестал работать.Приходится работать с внутренними ресурсами через удалленый рабочий стол (VPS), там VPN соединение устанавливается. Если ли способ настроить "тунель" c моего рабочего ПК и VPS, чтобы я как-бы подключался к VPS и у меня доступ был через его VPN?

Comment: можно попробовать пробросить с VPS реверс-туннель до вашего домашнего компа, и через него уже устанавливать VPN

Comment: Но безопасники вас за такое накажут, если они вообще понимают чем занимаются